# unable to join two tables based on common field mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my mysql database:

```
create table PopularCompanies(CompanyName varchar, WebDomain varchar)
create table CompanyMaster(CompanyName varchar, WebDomain varchar, field1 varchar, field2....)
```

I am trying to query the the values of field1, field2 etc based on shared webdomain field by using a join query. This is how I query:

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2... from CompanyMaster t1 join PopularCompanies t2 on t1.WebDomain=t2.WebDomain
```

I do not get results, despite having records in both tables with the same WebDomain field value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create sqlfiddle for it

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind : 1) There is something different in the characters in WebDomain between the two tables, a hidden character for instance, possibly a carriage return or some such. 2) the tables (or WebDomain Fields) have ended up with different collations - use SHOW CREATE TABLE to check this.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c434b/1

Comment: You nailed it. Each value of the "WebDomain" join field had a hidden character sitting at the end of the value, which I realised when I got zero results on doing a WHERE query with the exact value. I then had to use a combination of Replace() and Convert() in order to delete the character. After this, it worked like silk.